# How i can achive the best sensitivity for the user location?

Tags: ios, iphone, location, core-location

I'm writing an app that take (after user approvation) the user position form 5 minutes and then write a path over a map. I'm using Standard Location services

```
if (nil == locationManager)

 locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

In my paths i see some "accurancy mistake", so my question is, how i can achive the best result in sensitivity from user location? There's a way to communicate with phone gps outside the CLLocationManager (naturally i don't think so...)?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the locationManager's desiredFilter member to a suitable distance as per your requirement.

```
locationManager.desiredFilter = 200;//200mtr
```

This can be used in conjunction with "startMonitoringForRegion" api, where you can define an geo fencing region depending on the kind of accuracy you are looking for and get notified when the user crosses over the region.